# How to set the maximum number of times an ajax call should be made?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to limit the number of times an ajax call can be made to 30. How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(".clicass").on("click", function ($) { // When btn is pressed.
    jQuery(this).attr("disabled", true); // Disable the button, temp.
    let commentLikes = parseInt(jQuery(this).children('span').text()) + 1;
    jQuery(this).children('span').text(commentLikes.toString());

    let commentID = parseInt(jQuery(this).closest('article').attr('id').match(/\d+/));
    let ajaxThis = this;
    var datastr = '&comment-id=' + commentID + '&action=tutsplus_add_comment_meta';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
        data: datastr,
        success: function (data) {
            var $data = jQuery(data);
            jQuery(ajaxThis).attr("disabled", false);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

Also, I am new to jQuery if you see any ways my code could be improved, write a comment :)

Comment: Put the count in a global variable, increment it each time the function is called, and check if it's less than 30.

Comment: Why are you using `function ($)`? The argument to the click handler is the `Event` object, why would you use `$` as the name for this?

Comment: @Barmar I am using $ because I have seen other people use it. Usually I see a letter e, but in ajax calls I have seen the dollar sign. [Example](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html). What is the best practice?

Comment: That's `jQuery(function($)...)` which is a special case. That's just for running a function when the document is ready, and jQuery passes itself as the argument to the callback. It's not the same in an event handler.

Comment: That allows you to use `$(...)` instead of `jQuery(...)` inside that function, which you would need if you've redefined the global `$`.

Comment: @barmar thanks, and one last question: I want to limit the number of times the function is called on a specific button, but if they use a different button I want a different counter, how to make the counter only apply to specific buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.data()` method to associate a counter with each element. Increment the counter each time the handler is called, and return from the function when it reaches 30.

```js
jQuery(".clicass").on("click", function() { // When btn is pressed.
  let counter = jQuery(this).data("counter");
  if (!counter) {
    counter = 1;
  }
  counter++;
  if (counter > 30) {
    console.log("Reached limit, skipping");
    return;
  }
  jQuery(this).data("counter", counter + 1);
  jQuery(this).attr("disabled", true); // Disable the button, temp.
  let commentLikes = parseInt(jQuery(this).children('span').text()) + 1;
  jQuery(this).children('span').text(commentLikes.toString());

  let commentID = parseInt(jQuery(this).closest('article').attr('id').match(/\d+/));
  let ajaxThis = this;
  var datastr = '&comment-id=' + commentID + '&action=tutsplus_add_comment_meta';
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
    data: datastr,
    success: function(data) {
      var $data = jQuery(data);
      jQuery(ajaxThis).attr("disabled", false);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
    }

  });
  return false;
});
```